# Iterator to call class function in java

Tags: java

```
package test_run;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Al_class
{
  int x;

  Al_class() {
    x=0;
  }

  void increment(){
      ++x;
  }

  int get_value(){
      return x;
  }

    ArrayList<Al_class> class_declare(){
    //void class_declare(){
      Al_class alc1 = new Al_class();
      Al_class alc2 = new Al_class();
      Al_class alc3 = new Al_class();
      alc1.increment();
      alc1.increment();
      alc1.increment();
      alc2.increment();

      ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
      al.add(alc1);
      al.add(alc2);
      al.add(alc3);
      return al;
  }



} ///:~

class Main
{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Al_class a = new Al_class();
    ArrayList<Al_class> b;

    b=a.class_declare();
    a.class_declare();
    System.out.print(" Arraylist size= "+ b.size());

    for (Al_class c : b ){

        System.out.print("\n" + c.get_value() + "\n");
    }
    b.remove(0);
    System.out.print(" Arraylist size= "+ b.size());

    Iterator it= b.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print("\n" + it.next());
        // Al_class e=it.next();
        // System.out.print("\n" + e.get_value());          
    }
  }
}
```

How can I use iterator to call the object function `get_value`? Its not a homework, but self learning.

Comment: Why did you comment out the correct answer (in the `while (it.hasNext())` method).

Answer (score 2):

You must use generics, which means to change `Iterator` to `Iterator<A1_class>`:

```
Iterator<A1_class> it= b.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Al_class e=it.next();
    System.out.print("\n" + e);
    System.out.print("\n" + e.get_value());          
}
```

Comment: you are calling `it.next()` twice so, `A1_class e` will return a every 2nd element from the iterator and print the odd items in `sysout`.

Comment: @TheElite: thanks for notifying me, I simply uncommented the code from the sample ;-) Oh, the dangers of copy-and-paste!

Answer (score 0):

You can approach a few ways

**Explicit Cast**

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object o = it.next();
    if(o instanceof Al_class){
        Al_class e=(Al_class)o;
        System.out.print("\n" + e.get_value());  
    } 
}
```

**Generics**

```
Iterator<A1_class> it= b.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Al_class e=it.next();
    System.out.print("\n" + e.get_value());          
}
```

Your not really supposed to do explicit casting w/ type checking anymore, but its still in there and has limited use cases.